# Golang binary not start in docker container

Tags: docker

I write this Dockerfile

```
# Stage I
FROM golang:alpine as builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git ca-certificates
COPY . $GOPATH/src/realtime_chat/chat
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/realtime_chat/chat
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/websocket
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags="-w -s" -o /go/bin/chat
# Stage II
FROM alpine
COPY ./views /go/bin/views
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/chat /go/bin/chat
ENTRYPOINT [ "/go/bin/chat" ]
```

After I start container with `docker run -d -p 80:80 image_name`, container start and working, but i'm don't have response from app. But if i'm enter to container, stop and run app manualy by typing `./go/bin/chat` app start respond.
I tried to expose ports, changed entrypoint to cmd, change base image(for both stage)

Comment: What happens when you run the image using the interactive shell (ie, using the -it switch) and try to execute your binary? What is the error message?

Comment: @MarcBernier nothing, all works fine

Comment: Exact same path (/go/bin)? It is a bit weird that you switch between using $GOPATH and a hard-coded path, you may want to fix the entrypoint line.

Comment: @MarcBernier ok, i'm fixed path in `ENTRYPOINT`. Now all work fine. But why it not working? I seen examples in which this `ENTRYPOINT` working, and i'm creating app with `Dockerfile` like this from examples which works too.

Comment: What is $GOPATH set to?